# Finding UMVU stimator of $\frac{\lambda^3}{3!}e^{-\lambda}$ function for Poisson distribution $(Poiss(\lambda))$ sample

Tags: statistics, parameter-estimation

Let's say that we want to find Unbiased Minimum Variance estimator of $\lambda^2$ for a sample $X=(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ from Poisson distribution. We can consider $\overline{X}^2$ and notice that

$$\mathbb{E}(\overline{X}^2) = Var(\overline{X}) + \left(\mathbb{E}(\overline{X})\right)^2 =  \frac{1}{n^2} \cdot n \cdot Var(X_1) +  \lambda^2 = \lambda^2 + \frac{\lambda}{n} =  \lambda^2 + \mathbb{E}\left(\frac{1}{n}\overline{X} \right)$$

Which gives us that $\overline{X}^2 + \frac{1}{n}\overline{X}$ is what we are searching for: because it's a function of $\overline{X}$, which for exponential families is sufficient, and in this case also complete, statistic, then from Lehmann-Scheffe theorem we conclude that it's UMVU estimator.

---

Now, let's consider a function like: $$g(\lambda) = \frac{\lambda^3}{3!}e^{-\lambda}.$$

Which is actually a probability $P(X_i=3)$. What can we do with this, to find an UMVU estimator of this one? I was wondering to start, just like above, from considering

$$T(X)= \frac{\overline{X}^3}{3!}e^{-\overline{X}},$$

and eventually adjust it with some other components, but trying to find expected value of this almost made me cry. I was thinking about transforming it somehow and using Basu theorem make things easier, but not sure how.

Any advice how to do this? Or maybe I can find the UMVUE easier here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start from 
$$
g_n = \mathcal{I}\{X_1 = 3\},
$$
as an unbiased estimator. Then, using Rao-Blackwell, compute 
$$
g_n^{RB} = \mathbb{E}[g_n|\sum _{i=1}^n X_i =t]. 
$$
Note that $g_n^{RB}$ is an unbiased estimator and function of the complete minimal sufficient statistic $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. Thus, by Lehmann-Scheffe, it is a UMVUE.

Namely,
\begin{align}
g_n^{RB} &=  \mathbb{E}[g_n|\sum _{i=1}^n X_i =t]\\
         &= \frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 3) \mathbb{P}( \sum _{i=2}^n X_i =t - 3)}{\mathbb{P}( \sum _{i=1}^n X_i =t)}\\
        & =\frac{e^{-\lambda}\lambda^3/3! \times e^{-\lambda (n-1)}\lambda^{t-3} (n-1)^{t-3} / (t-3)!}{e^{-\lambda n}\lambda^t n^t/t!} \\
         & = \left( \frac{n-1}{n} \right)^{t} \binom{t}{3}(n-1)^{-3} \\
         & = \left( 1 - \frac{1}{n} \right)^{n\bar{x}_n} \binom{n\bar{x}_n}{3}(n-1)^{-3}.
\end{align}
Now, for validation, you can use the continuous mapping theorem and the WLLN. Note that $\bar{X}_n \xrightarrow{p} \lambda$, same is true for $\frac{1}{n-1}\sum X_i \xrightarrow{p} \lambda$, and note that $(1-1/n)^n \xrightarrow{} e^{-1}$. Hence, combining it all, the estimator converges to $g(\lambda)$.

Comment: What does $\mathcal{I}$  in $g_n$ stands for? Fisher Information?

Comment: $\mathcal{I}$ - indicator function, $g_n$ - an estimator of $g(\lambda)$

Comment: So we have: $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 3)=\frac{\lambda^3}{3!}e^{-\lambda}$, and because for $X\sim Poiss(\lambda)$ we have $\sum_{i=1}^n \sim Poiss(n \lambda)$, thus we have $\mathbb{P}( \sum _{i=1}^n X_i =t) = \frac{(n \lambda)^t}{t!}e^{-n \lambda}$, then similarly $\mathbb{P}(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i =t-3)=
\frac{(n \lambda)^{t-3} }{(t-3)!} e^{-n \lambda}$, which gives me $\frac{\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 3) \mathbb{P}( \sum _{i=1}^n X_i =t - 3)}{\mathbb{P}( \sum _{i=1}^n X_i =t)} = \binom{t}{3}e^{-\lambda}(1-\frac{1}{n})^3(n-1)^{-3}$. How to I transform this into your form?

Comment: Also, what does $t$ stands for? Where do we know $t$ from?

Comment: 1. Please check your calculations. The estimator cannot be a function of $\lambda$. 2. As I stated, $t$ is some value of $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$. I'll add more steps a little later.

Comment: Thank you. This $\lambda$ of mine comes from $\mathbb{P}(X_1 = 3)=\frac{\lambda^3}{3!}e^{-\lambda}$. Should I just replace $\lambda$ with $\overline{X}$? And, if I understand correctly now, the $t$ value depends on sample and it's $t=\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$, does it mean that I can replace $t$ with $n \overline{X}$?

Comment: Please the edited answer

Comment: Thank you for help and explanation, really helpful! I understand it now :-)

Answer (score 1):

for n number of samples
define an indicator function, $I(X_1)=1$ if $X_1=3$ and $0$ otherwise, notice that, $E(I(X_1))$ is an unbiased estimator of the given expression.
now as $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$ is the complete sufficient statistic for the poission family, using lehman scheffe theorem we can conclude that, $E(I(X_1)|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=t)$ is the UMVUE of $\frac{\lambda^3 e^-\lambda}{3!}$

$E(I(X_1)|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=t)$
= $P(X_1=3|\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=t)$
=$\frac{P(X_1=3,\sum_{i=2}^n X_i=t-3)}{P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=t)}$
=$\frac{P(X_1=3)P(\sum_{i=2}^n X_i=t-3)}{P(\sum_{i=1}^n X_i=t)}$
=$\frac{\frac{\lambda^3 e^{-\lambda}}{3!}\frac{((n-1)\lambda)^{t-3} e^{-(n-1)\lambda}}{(t-3)!}}{\frac{(n\lambda)^t e^{-n\lambda}}{t!}}$
=$\frac{t(t-1)(t-2)}{3!}\frac{(n-1)^{t-3}}{n^t}$

now replace all the t with $\sum_{i=1}^n X_i$
and that is your required UMVUE.